# What would be the fastest way to connect to a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, network-programming, server

I have an HTTP server receiving new client connections all the time. Each time, I have to reconnect to the Cassandra cluster (each client is attached to a new process via a fork() call.)

I have two problems:

- Speed: I'd like to make use of a connection as fast as possible;
- Robustness: any one of the Cassandra node could be down.

I would imagine that the best mechanism will work with any cluster, not just Cassandra.

We use thrift to connect, although we may change that later. Either way, as far as network connections are concerned, we just do the regular `socket()`, `bind()`, and `connect()` call sequence.

Most of the code I have seen dealing with similar problems is very serial: it tries to connect to host 1, if it times out, try again with host 2, etc. until all hosts are exhausted.

I was thinking I could instead create one thread per connection attempt (with some sort of limit like 3, 4, or 5 parallel attempts--the number will depend on the size of the Cassandra cluster.) However, I am although thinking that if all connections succeed, I am probably going to waste a lot of time on the cluster side...

Is there a specific way this sort of a thing is generally resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most (if not all) of these features (failover, smart request routin, retries) are available in the DataStax drivers for Cassandra.
2. If possible you should migrate away from Thrift.
3. If you really really have to (please consider the time to develop and maintain this solution on a protocol that has been deprecated for a long while) create your own, you could take some inspiration from the DataStax drivers.

Comment: I wrote my C++ library at the time they still were working on 0.8 and the CQL was not really viewed as ready back then... Seems to work just fine at this point with thrift, but we have to finish a project before taking the time to switch. Anyway, I will try to look at said drivers and get inspiration from their code.